# Watson Conversation API says: 'Patterns are defined but type is not specified.'

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am trying to call the `updateValue` method of the Watson Conversation API using the Watson SDK for Node.js. The request updates the patterns of the `patterns`-type entity value.

My request fails with a `400 Bad Request` and the message:

```
[ { message: 'Patterns are defined but type is not specified.',
       path: '.patterns' } ],
```

Here is the code I'm using to call the API - pretty standard.:

```
      let params = {
        workspace_id: '<redacted>',
        entity: 'myEntityType',
        type: 'patterns', // tried with and without this line
        value: 'myCanonicalValue',
        new_patterns: ['test'],
      };

      watsonApi.updateValue(params, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Error returned by Watson when updating an entity value.');
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(response);
        }
      });
```

Actually, what the request is doing is trying to delete a pattern from the pattern list. Since there is no endpoint for deleting patterns, I fetch the list of patterns, delete the one I need to delete from the pattern list, and send the now-reduced patterns list via the `updateValue` method. In the above example, imagine the pattern list was `['test', 'test2']`. By calling `updateValue` with `['test']` only, we are deleting the `test2` pattern.

I am using a previous API version but I've also tested it in the Assistant API Explorer and the version `2018-07-10` results in the same problem when sending a raw request body formed as follows:

```
{
  "patterns": ["test"]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or did I forget a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, but it is a non-intuitive parameter name. The service accepts a `type` parameter and the Node SDK has a wrapper parameter called `new_type`. If you are using this to update patterns and not synonyms (the default), then you need to specify `new_type` as `"patterns"` even though the parameter is listed as optional.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Watson Conversation Node.js SDK.

To avoid this, always add `new_type: 'patterns'` to the `params`:

```
  let params = {
    workspace_id: '<redacted>',
    entity: 'myEntityType',
    new_type: 'patterns',
    value: 'myCanonicalValue',
    new_patterns: ['test'],
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the [Watson Assistant API for updateValue](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/node.html?node#update-value) the following way:

The `new_type` parameter is not required, valid values are `synonyms` or `patterns`. However, if you don't provide that parameter, the default kicks in. According to the documentation the default is `synonyms`. This would explain the error when you pass in patterns.